# RewriteURL with apache2 @username to /user/username

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

This is fairly simple but I am having a hard time figuring out what to do I searched in the apache2 rewriteurl documentation but didnt find anything helpful.
you go to url.com/@myusername and apache points you to url.com/username/@myusername and keeps the URL on the browser intact with [L,NE,P]

```
RewriteURL @username /user/username
```

please note I only want to redirect what starts with @ sign and take it as a username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First activate mod_rewrite,

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Then restart apache2,

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

create the .htaccess file in the web root. This must be the document root you provided in the apache config.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+) user/$1 [QSA]
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the match start with @ symbol, use the regex as below,

```
RewriteRule ^(@[A-Za-z0-9]+) user/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: first off thank you Rohit! I only want to redirect what starts with @ sign. I made edit to question to make sure its clearer.

Comment: Updated my answer, see that helps you.